# Gnuplot - creating a 3D-mesh or net

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to generate a three dimensional mesh or net with variable length at each of three sides. How to achive that in gnuplot?
Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very detailed... furthermore, no code and no research effort visible (By the way, that's what people expect here on SO). In gnuplot console, e.g. check `help do`, `help print`, `help sprintf` or other keywords.

A guess what you might want could be the following:

**Code:**

```
### creating a 3D grid
reset session
set view equal xyz

dx = 0.7
dy = 0.8
dz = 0.6

set print $Data
do for [z=0:3] {
    do for [y=0:4] {
        do for [x=0:5] {
            print sprintf("%g %g %g",x*dx,y*dy,z*dz)
        }
        print ""
    }
    print ""
}
set print

set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set ztics 1
set view 73,53

splot $Data u 1:2:3 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Dear theozh, thank You very much. Sorry for the lack of informations. I actually searched a lot in google and this is how I got to know this forum, but I found no answer. I wanted to draw a picture of how I imagined the plot to look like, but this would not have looked nice. Despite all, Your solution is already very good. I'd just like to have lines even between the layers. Then it is a perfect mesh or net or grid or however one might call it. I actually want to visualize the effect of gravitational waves on space - i.e. how poins in space strech an shrink under the influence of grav. waves.